# for the following equation, state whether it is homogenous or inhomogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y^{\prime\prime\prime}+y=9$$

I cant understand why this equation is inhomogenous.
Homogenous is of the form $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+yP(x)=0$.
Inhomogenous is of the form $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+yP(x)=Q(x)$

Comment: $Q(x)$ doesn't have to have any "x"s in it, it can be a constant

Comment: oh right. and P(x) also could be a constant? in this case one?

Comment: It absolutely can :)

Comment: inhomogeneous is when the RHS $\ne 0$